# Reordering a list by element in list and remove specified rows in list

Tags: r, split, reorderlist

Continuation to this question: [Add row in R dataframe by unique factor in column showing percent change by Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536053/add-row-in-r-dataframe-by-unique-factor-in-column-showing-percent-change-by-mont)

```
testing <- data.frame(
  MONTH = c("MTD: 12", "MTD: 12", "MTD: 11", "MTD: 12", "MTD: 12", "MTD: 12"), 
  YEAR = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2014), 
  Client = c("A.", "A.", "A.", "B.", "B.", "B."), 
  Revenue = c(320, 205, 166L, 152, 150, 138),
  Col1 = c(651, 485, 533, 3932, 171, 436), 
  Col2 = c(478, 335, 305, 238, 115, 251), 
  Col3 = c(73, 69, 57, 6, 67, 57), 
  Col4 = c(6.7, 6.1, 5.5, 6.4, 13.1, 5.5)
)

# subset just the month=12 rows
test12 <- testing[testing$MONTH=="MTD: 12", ]
test12 <- test12[order(test12$Client, test12$YEAR), ]

# define a function to calculate percent change
pctchange <- function(x) {
  L <- length(x)
  c(NA, 100 * (x[-1] - x[-L]) / x[-L])
}

# calculate percent change for all columns, by client
change <- apply(test12[, c("Revenue", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")], 2,
  function(y) unlist(tapply(y, test12$Client, pctchange)))
change <- data.frame(change)
names(change) <- paste0("d", names(change))
test12b <- cbind(test12[, c("MONTH", "YEAR", "Client")], change)

# merge back with monthly data
merge(testing, test12b, all=TRUE)
```

So after running this code you get a list that has been splitted by client.

I want to run the following code that will essentially remove the 2nd row if the number of rows for that factor (the client) is greater than 2.

I tried this already and it didn't work:

```
testing<-ifelse(length(splitresult)>2,splitresult[-2,],splitresult)
```

Ultimate goal out of all of this:

1) To just get the percent change of the last year with the previous year and don't show the inbetween stuff like NA for the previous year. But if it is a new client I do want the NA there to specify it is a new client. So that is why I tried out the code above which didn't work.

2) I want to reorder the clients in the split by Revenue in MTD: 12 2014.

```
splitlist[order(sapply(splitlist, function(x) (x[["Revenue"]])))]
```

(Didn't work: assume splitlist is the name of the list)

If anyone can help me with either question it would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use the `dplyr` package?

Comment: I haven't. I think I need to use sapply for the 2nd part of the question but not sure how to go about it with the month/year involved. I have edited the question to show you what I have tried @Jubbles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `plyr` package would help here. For example, instead of the last line of code where you use `ifelse`, you could try

```
library(plyr)
out = ddply(splitresult, "Client", function(x){
  if(dim(x)[1] > 2) x = x[-2,]
  return(x)
})
```

Here, `x` is a client-specific data frame, and `out` is the result of combining the rows of a bunch of client-specific data frames.

You might also check out `lubridate`, which will make dates and times easier to deal with. As mentioned in the comments, `dplyr` would also be helpful, as would the rest of the "Hadleyverse" of packages for cleaning and plotting data. The solutions to your questions 1 and 2, along with the whole process of cleaning and summarizing, will be much cleaner and easier with the right tools.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. The only thing I need to figure out now from this is to separate it into different dataframes by client by Revenue of MTD: 2015. Then good to go. I will ask that in a different post though if that is preferred. @landau

Comment: Sure thing. If you change `ddply` to `dlply` above, you'll have a list of client-specific data frames in `out` instead of a single data frame. Semantically, I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about separating by Revenue of MTD: 2015. Usually, I think of separating data frames according to features such as date, not levels such as December 2015.

Comment: So when I make that list, it is ordered alphabetically by Client. I want to order the list of clients by Revenue of MTD 12: 2015

Comment: This will list the Clients by revenue